# Loading large SAS file in R gives "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 109.3 Mb"

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, sas

### Issue

I have an 11.3GB SAS file (*mydata.sas7bdat*, see *Sidenote #1* below) that I wanted to load with the ***sas7bdat*** package in R, but I get:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 109.3 Mb.

Using RStudio, which tries to import the file with ***haven***, I also get:

> Is this a valid SPSS, SAS or STATA file?
>
> Evaluation error: cannot allocate vector of size 109.3 Mb.

I have also tried using ***pandas*** in Python with the similar outcome of memory running out.

---

> ### Sidenotes
>
> 1) *mydata.sas7bdat* is a merger of [file1](https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/nrd/stats/FileSpecifications_NRD_2013_Core.TXT), [file2](https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/nrd/stats/FileSpecifications_NRD_2013_Hospital.TXT), [file3](https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/nrd/stats/FileSpecifications_NRD_2013_Severity.TXT), and [file4](https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/nrd/stats/FileSpecifications_NRD_2013_DX_PR_GRPS.TXT).
>
> 2) I am using a computer with Win10 x64, 32GB RAM, and all unnecessary apps and processes closed.
>
> 3) I cannot get the data file in a truncated or alternate file format (eg, CSV)

Comment: Have you tried `rm(list = ls())` before importing?

Comment: Also, I think a sas7bdat file is a compressed file. So you might run out of RAM of it is uncompressed.

Comment: @hpesoj626 same error even after using `rm(list = ls())`

Comment: Generally speaking the only solution to memory issues when loading data into R is to either get more ram or load less data (store in a db, and only pull in what you need in chunks).

Comment: Can you do some manipulation of the file in SAS first? It is in a wide format currently, e.g. `DX1`-`DX25` for each diagnosis running across the page. This could be stored in one long diagnosis table and probably save you 50% of the filesize if most cases only have a handful of diagnoses.

Comment: There were 14 million records in one of those, 14 million in another, 2006 in yet another, and 14 million in the fourth. You might be out of luck. (There are some package that do large file operations.)  Who did the merger? Has it ever been in one piece within R? And, have you tried to start with a clean session of Windoze and R?

Comment: try `gc(TRUE)`, to free the memory. How many rows and columns is your SAS file ?. (mydata.sas7bdat).

Comment: `haven::read_sas()` has a (although experimental) `cols_only` parameter, you could try loading only a few columns and see what happens.

Comment: @thelatemail will SAS allow me to do data manipulation without running out of memory the way R and Python did? Otherwise I am unable to manipulate the file in SAS first.

Comment: @42- I don't have access to the person or computer that did the original merger. And yes I did start with a clean session of Windows and R.

Comment: @DominicComtois thank you for the `cols_only` suggestion, I did `read_sas("D:\\mydata.sas7bdat", cols_only = c("AGE"))` and it printed the AGE column of the first 10 rows and then noted that there are 14,325,162 more rows. Is it possible extract just the first 10 rows but with all the columns?

Comment: Not sure how well it works, but SAS lets you convert files to CSV (http://dumbmatter.com/sas7bdat/).

Comment: Not that I know of... With some looping, you could read column by column and eliminate rows however.

Comment: @DominicComtois it took a very long time to simply show the first 10 rows of the AGE column, which I imagine is because it was also reading the remaining 14million? Is it possible to limit reading of rows to only the first 10 as well (i.e., without having to read all and then eliminate)? Additionally, how can I read column by column without explicitly providing the column name?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is as good as it gets, at least for now... Maybe in the future, `haven`'s function will evolve... But your best bet would be to work on the data in SAS and export it to a text/csv format. Then you could use `read.table()` with `nrows=` parameter. Or set up a database to which you could connect from R... (It's possible to connect to a SAS library through ODBC, but for this you need to have SAS installed as well. And you wouldn't gain so much IMO.)

Comment: I think that solution may be simple if you stop to solve it directly. SAS never load the whole file into the memory. It's old good system and the most SAS procedures works in LIMITED memory (!) R load ALL data in memory. It' a problem. You will not be able to work with such file in R anyway. R is not for DIG DATA. Possible use data.table package, but... Suggest some ideas: 1) load the file into some database and work with it from R using connection and SQL 2) use SAS to split the file for some smaller files 3) drop unused information from the SAS file